# Can I use a custom component in a different Namespace within Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, visualforce-component

I want to make some slight modifications to the visualforce page display for an application that was installed via a managed package.

The manage package allows me to view the VisualForce code for the pages (but not components) but does not allow editing.

I can replicate the page by copying and pasting the code to a new page but can't save it because a component its trying to reference is in a different namespace. The code that is failing to load the component correctly is:

```
    <c:Taskboard boardId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.boardId}" 
                recordId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordId}" 
                relationshipName="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relationshipName}" 
                showHeader="false" 
                showFilters="true"
                showBoardSwitcher="true"
                embeddedIframesAllowed="true"
                touchScope="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.touchScope=='true',true,false)}" >
    </c:Taskboard>
```

I need to be able to access the component in the Namespace either from a page not in the namespace (not sure what the syntax would be to add the namespace to this component)

OR

I need to designate that my VF page is part of that namespace so it will have access to the same components without a change in the component syntax.

Are either of these two things possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of creating your own page which references the Taskboard component may be viable, there are however a few limiting factors which could affect this approach.

1. Component definition - The Taskboard component will need to have been defined as `global` to allow you to call this component from outside the installed managed package.
2. Component Attribute definition - To access the attributes on the taskboard component such as the `boardId=""` element each of these will also need to have been defined as `global`.
3. License issues for the package - If you create an unmanaged page which references a component in a licensed managed package you may run into issues if the viewing user does not have a license assigned.

To find out if a component is global you can navigate to the component via **Setup -> Develop -> Visualforce Components ->** then either create a list view to filter the results down or find the component in question manually. If you are looking at a managed component then you will see a breakdown of the elements defined as global and therefore should be useable.

---

Regarding your question about the two possible options you would like to know about, the first option of the two would be possible.

*I need to be able to access the component in the Namespace either from a page not in the namespace (not sure what the syntax would be to add the namespace to this component)*

This can be achieved by replacing the `c:` part of the component call with the namespace of the package that the taskboard is in followed by the `:` then the component name.

E.g. 
if the taskboard was installed as part of a package with the namespace "abcd" the syntax to call the component within your visualforce page would be:

```
<abcd:taskboard boardId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.boardId}" 
            recordId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordId}" 
            relationshipName="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relationshipName}" 
            showHeader="false" 
            showFilters="true"
            showBoardSwitcher="true"
            embeddedIframesAllowed="true"
            touchScope="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.touchScope=='true',true,false)}" >
</abcd:Taskboard>`
```